# 2 player Tic-Tac-Toe Game

Tags: java

I am trying to make a two player tic-tac-toe game but I cannot get it so that when Its the next players turn it will print out an O
and then when its the next player it will print print out an X.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToeMain{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] Board = new String[][] {
            {" ", " ", " "}, {" ", " ", " "," "}, 
            {" ", " ", " "," "},{" "," "," "," "},{" "," "," "}};
        grid1(Board,scan);
        System.out.println("Where do you wan't your x to be?");
        move1(Board,scan);
    }
    public static void grid1(String[][] Board, Scanner scan){
        System.out.println("A " + Board[0][1] +Board[0][0]+ " | " + Board[3][1] + " | "+                Board[0][2]);
        System.out.println(" -------------");
        System.out.println("B " + Board[1][1] +Board[1][0]+ " | " + Board[3][2] + " | "+   Board[1][2]);
        System.out.println(" -------------");
        System.out.println("C " + Board[3][3] +Board[2][0]+ " | " + Board[2][1] + " | "+ Board[2][2]);

    }
    public static void move1(String[][] Board, Scanner scan){
        int Input = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0;i<100;i++){
            if (Input == 1){
                Board[0][1]="X";
                grid1(Board, scan);
                move2(Board,scan);
            } else if(Input == 2){
                Board[3][1]="X";
                grid1(Board,scan);
                move2(Board,scan);
            } else if(Input == 3){
                Board[0][2]="X";
                grid1(Board,scan);
                move2(Board,scan);
            } else if(Input == 4){
                Board[1][1]="X";
                grid1(Board,scan);
                move2(Board,scan);
            } else if(Input ==5){
                Board[3][2]="X";
                grid1(Board,scan);
                move2(Board,scan);
            } else if(Input ==6){
                Board[1][2]="X";
                grid1(Board,scan);
                move2(Board,scan);
            } else if(Input ==7){
                Board[3][3]="X";
                grid1(Board,scan);
                move2(Board,scan);
            } else if(Input == 8){
                Board[2][1]="X";
                grid1(Board,scan);
                move2(Board,scan);
            } else if(Input ==9){
                Board[2][2]="X";
                grid1(Board,scan);
                move2(Board,scan);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void move2(String[][] Board, Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Where do you wan't your O to be?");
        int Input = scan.nextInt();
        if (Input == 1){
            Board[0][1]="O";
            grid1(Board, scan);
            move3(Board, scan,Input);
        } else if(Input == 2){
            Board[3][1]="O";
            grid1(Board,scan);
            move3(Board, scan,Input);
        } else if(Input == 3){
            Board[0][2]="O";
            grid1(Board,scan);
            move3(Board, scan,Input);
        } else if(Input == 4){
            Board[1][1]="O";
            grid1(Board,scan);
        } else if(Input ==5){
            Board[3][2]="O";
            grid1(Board,scan);
            move3(Board, scan,Input);
        } else if(Input ==6){
            Board[1][2]="O";
            grid1(Board,scan);
            move3(Board, scan,Input);
        } else if(Input ==7){
            Board[3][3]="O";
            grid1(Board,scan);
            move3(Board, scan,Input);
        } else if(Input == 8){
            Board[2][1]="O";
            grid1(Board,scan);
            move3(Board, scan,Input);
        } else if(Input ==9){
            Board[2][2]="O";
            grid1(Board,scan);
            move3(Board, scan,Input);
        }
    }
    public static void move3(String[][] Board, Scanner scan, int Input){
        if (Input == 1){
            Board[0][1]="X";
            grid1(Board, scan);
        } else if(Input == 2){
            Board[3][1]="X";
            grid1(Board,scan);
        } else if(Input == 3){
            Board[0][2]="X";
            grid1(Board,scan);
        } else if(Input == 4){
            Board[1][1]="X";
            grid1(Board,scan);
        } else if(Input ==5){
            Board[3][2]="X";
            grid1(Board,scan);
        } else if(Input ==6){
            Board[1][2]="X";
            grid1(Board,scan);
        } else if(Input ==7){
            Board[3][3]="X";
            grid1(Board,scan);
        } else if(Input == 8){
            Board[2][1]="X";
            grid1(Board,scan);
        } else if(Input ==9){
            Board[2][2]="X";
            grid1(Board,scan);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and spare SO this monster.

Comment: You should look into loops.. this looks like a nightmare

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java code for TicTacToe Game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667319/java-code-for-tictactoe-game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general coding practice you want to reduce all redundancy. In your code there is a lot of redundant code which, after cleanup, may reveal your problem.

First I would write a helper method that puts a symbol, X or O, onto the board.

```
public void addMove(String letter, int input){}
```

This way you do not need the move1, move2 methods.
In your main you can keep track of whose turn it is using a boolean. I also recommending writing a method that checks if the game is over.

```
while(!isOver()){
   boolean xTurn = false;
   if(xTurn){
      addMove("X", /*Their input*/); 
   } else {
      addMove("O"m /*Their input*/);
   }
   xTurn = !xTurn; //Set xTurn to the opposite
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

just a tip: as you have a 3x3 matrix

```
public static void move(char c){
    int row = (input-1) / 3;
    int col = (input-1) % 3;
    board[row][col]=c;
}
```